# Should I replace this tube or try to replace the core?

Tags: valves, presta

I just borrowed this old bike and realized could not pump up the back wheel. When I saw the valve, it looks like the valve core is missing. I tried to install a new presta core but it did not fit. Should I continue to install a new presta core or go to a bike shop to replace the tube?[image][image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The valve core is not visible in the photo so it must have snapped off and is not present. It looks to be non-replaceable because the remaining part looks like one single piece, so the tube should be replaced rather than attempt any further repair.

Also have the wheel(s) checked for loose spokes, the spoke pictured is showing some threads(?) so may have loosened a lot. Plus the chain is very rusty, this doesn't look like a bike in roadworthy condition as it stands.

Comment: Thank you for your advices, so I should replace both the tyre and the inner tube?  Could I just replace the inner tube and keep the tyre? And could the loose spoke be fixed? I know the chain is quite rusty but I think it is just outside.

Comment: You should replace the inner tube but I can't tell you about the tyre. There is nothing concerning about the tyre in the picture, but there isn't much of it visible. Loose spokes (if any) can be tightened yes no problem. Doing so will increase the life of the wheel

Comment: The chain also looks a little sad, as it needs to be cleaned and lubricated.

Comment: @Swifty: This valve could well be a rare Italian Regina valve from the looks of it.